# Can you put retries on an individual TaskFlow @task?

Tags: airflow, airflow-taskflow

All the examples of retries on tasks in the Airflow docs are on things like BashOperator. Manual tests on version 2.5.1 show that this doesn't work on Taskflow:

```
    @task
    def test_retries(retries=2):
        raise ValueError("I failed, please retry")

    test_retries()
```

Is there any way to put retries on a particular Taskflow task, not just default args for all tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes absolutely, but you set it (and other BaseOperator parameters like `pool`, `email_on_failure`, `retry_delay`, `queue`, etc.) on the decorator itself:

```py
@task(retries=2)
def test_retries():
    raise ValueError("I failed, please retry")

test_retries()
```